# iOS behavior of changing UIImageView bounds.size.height

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, resize

At start `UIImageViewObj frame = CGRectMake(20, 350, 20, 1);`

In code I do next:
`[UIImageViewObj setBounds: CGRectMake(20, 350, 20, 200)];`

Changing the bounds height of UIImageView at run time a change occurs from the center of a UIImageViewObj up and down, how to make change happen from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Hi, can you please try and be more clear about the behavior of the UIImage?

Comment: When I change height in Interface Builder, there is position selector at the left side of Size / Position block, when I change position to left-bottom corner and change height it's all good, but at runtime it change from the center of the UIImageView.

Comment: Are you talking about the anchor point of the UIImageView?

Comment: I think yes. There is Size / Position block in Interface Builder. Right part of it is X, Y, W, H size params and left is position points (top-left, top-center, top-right, center-left, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the anchor point you can just do

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5)
```

this will set the anchor point to the middle. if you want it in the left bottom part

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,1);
```

Just make sure you add Quazrtcore to your frameworks

Hope i understood you correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I don't know why anchor point resets on runtime :(

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageViewObj.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
```

Comment: I use "scale to fit" and with Or.Ron answer all works good for me. Thank you.